# Residual analysis and two-way interaction terms

Tags: regression, self-study

I'm a bit confused on some of the terminology involved in my assignment, which is shown in the following image:

[image]

I understand the main idea behind residual analysis is checking if the main assumptions are in line. This usually involves plotting residuals against fitted values and getting a normal probability plot for general diagnostics. 
The assignment is specifically asking to check if the two-way interaction terms (in relation to the residuals) are necessary for the model.

My main questions are: What exactly is a two-way interaction term? What characteristics of the residuals justify a two-way interaction term?

Comment: Are all your IVs factors?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with IVs factors?

Comment: You have a y-variable (response, dependent variable) and two  predictors/ x-variables/*independent variables*. Are those two independent variables  "grouping" variables (like say treatment group or sex -- i.e. *factors*) or are they - by contrast - numeric (like say 'dosage in ml')?

Comment: Or more briefly, *please describe the variables in your problem more clearly*

Comment: In my regression Data I only have numeric values for my independent variables. I am inept to describe the technical specifics. But in this assignment I am running a regression for Patient Satisfaction as a response variable with Age, Illness severity and Anxiety level as quantitative levels represented numerically as predictors.

Comment: 1. How are each of these variables recorded?  Is illness severity *categorical* for example?   2. Is it specified which of those three variables are in the two-way ANOVA (note that one must be omitted)?

Comment: There are no categories involved in any of the variables. There is no categorical description for what level of Illness severity it is involved in.It is the same with all of the other independent variables

Comment: Okay thanks. That sounds rather odd but it should be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)): 
An "interaction variable" is a variable constructed from an original set of variables to try to represent either all of the interaction present or some part of it. In exploratory statistical analyses it is common to use products of original variables [image]as the basis of testing whether interaction is present with the possibility of substituting other more realistic interaction variables at a later stage.

Based on this definition, wouldn't the magnitude of your residual be significantly different with and with out the interaction term?